# How to add title to json format output in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have used a sql query to generate a sql string in codeigniter.

```
    $result['tc'] = $this->db->query("select * from stationList");
```

then I pass it to the view ith the command:

```
    $this->load->view('jsontc',$result);
```

then using foreach loop to change it into array and encode it to json:

```
    $emparray = array();

foreach ($tc as $row)
{

$emparray[] = $row;

}

$page = json_encode(array('stationList' => $emparray));
echo $page.
```

so i get the following result

```
{
  "stationList":[
    {
  "no":"1",
  "location":"Temple Mall North",
  "districtL":"Kowloon",
  "districtS":"Wong Tai Sin",
  "address":"Temple Mall North Carpark, Level 3,\n136 Lung Cheung Rd, Wong Tai Sin, Kln",
  "provider":"CLP",
  "parkingNo":"320-322",
  "img":"\/EV\/PublishingImages\/common\/map\/map_thumb\/Entrance_Lung%20Cheung.jpg",
  "lat":"22.3425903320313",
  "lng":"114.190719604492",
  "type":"SemiQuick"
},
```

but how can I add a title to each set of record like the following?

```
{
  "stationList":[
    station{
  "no":"1",
  "location":"Temple Mall North",
  "districtL":"Kowloon",
  "districtS":"Wong Tai Sin",
  "address":"Temple Mall North Carpark, Level 3,\n136 Lung Cheung Rd, Wong Tai Sin, Kln",
  "provider":"CLP",
  "parkingNo":"320-322",
  "img":"\/EV\/PublishingImages\/common\/map\/map_thumb\/Entrance_Lung%20Cheung.jpg",
  "lat":"22.3425903320313",
  "lng":"114.190719604492",
  "type":"SemiQuick"
},
  station{...
```

Comment: What you asking ... is it even valid json/json array? Please post the proper final format.

Comment: I want to add the title "station" in front of each record of json.

Comment: Won't the same key break your json array?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to choose a unique identifier for your key so i have chosen the `no` You can try :

```
foreach ($tc as $row)
{
   $emparray["{$row['no']}"] = $row;
}
```